# module.db is a list of object, known only after apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
rds.tf:-

module "db" {
  **count  = var.environment == "dev" || var.environment == "qa" ? 1 : 0**
  source = "../rds"
  identifier = var.db_name
  engine                     = var.rds_engine
  engine_version             = var.rds_engine_version

output.tf:

output "rds_instance_endpoint" {
  description = "The connection endpoint"
  value       = module.db.db_instance_endpoint
}

ERROR:-

Error: Unsupported attribute
   on outputs.tf line 28, in output "rds_instance_endpoint":
   28:   value       = module.db.db_instance_endpoint
   module.db is a list of object, known only after apply

Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "db_instance_endpoint" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
```

getting the above error while declaring count in the rds.tf module.
if I remove count then its working fine, not sure what is this error.

Answer (score 13):

The error message in this case is the sentence "Can't access attributes on a list of objects", not the sentence "module.db is a list of object, known only after apply"; the latter is just additional context to help you understand the error message that follows.

In other words, Terraform is telling you that `module.db` is a list of objects *and* that it's invalid to use `.db_instance_endpoint` ("accessing an attribute") on that list.

The root problem here is that you have a module object that may or may not exist, and so you need to explain to Terraform how you want to handle the situation where it doesn't exist.

One answer would be to change your output value to return a set of instance endpoints that would be empty in environments other than the dev and QA environments:

```
output "rds_instance_endpoints" {
  description = "The connection endpoints for any database instances in this environment."
  value       = toset(module.db[*].db_instance_endpoint)
}
```

Here I used [the "splat" operator](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) to take the `db_instance_endpoint` attribute value *for each instance of the module*, which currently means that it will either be a single-element set or an empty set depending on the situation. This approach most directly models the underlying implementation and would give you the freedom to add additional instances of this module in future if you need to, but you might consider the fact that this is a multi-instance module to be an implementation detail which should be encapsulated in the module itself.

---

The other main option, which *does* hide that implementation detail of the underlying module being a list, would be to have your output value be `null` in the situation where there are no instances of the module, or to be a single string when there is one instance. For that, we can slightly adapt the above example to use [the `one` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/one) instead of [the `toset` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/toset):

```
output "rds_instance_endpoints" {
  description = "The connection endpoint for the database instance in this environment, if any."
  value       = one(module.db[*].db_instance_endpoint)
}
```

The `one` function has three possible outcomes depending on the number of elements in the given collection:

- If the collection has no elements, it will return `null`.
- If the collection has one element, it will return just the value of that element.
- If the collection has more than one element, it will fail with an error message. But note that this outcome is impossible in your case, because `count` can only be set to zero or one.

Null values can potentially be annoying to deal with if this data is being returned to a calling module for use elsewhere, but sometimes it's the most reasonable representation of the described infrastructure and so worth that additional complexity. For *root module* output values in particular, Terraform will treat a null value as if the output value were not set at all, hiding it in the messaging from `terraform apply`, and so this second strategy is often the best choice in situations where your primary motivation is to return this information in the user interface for a human to use for some subsequent action.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Martin. I tried changing the output variable value like this module.db.*.db_instance_endpoint but the problem is terraform is trying to recreate the existing rds instance.
I've try toset & one approach which you mentioned and check whether its recreating the resource or not.